# How to debug basic_string::_M_construct null not void error?

Tags: c++, string

So my program which is long and big, throws this error when I call SIGINT.

The issue is that 1) I'm not sure what the error is referring to. Something about strings?
And 2) more importantly, the debug message doesn't point me to any line of code. With a codebase that's big, it's hard to pinpoint the problem.

Any tips on how to debug these kind of messages?

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: If you run your program in a debugger, it'll probably break on this line and you can get a backtrace.  Your particular error looks like you're constructing an `std::string` with `nullptr` or the moral equivalent.

Comment: You're using a null pointer to initialize a string, that's UB.  You need to follow the standard debugging steps to narrow down where this is happening.  Nice guide here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are calling the ```std::string``` constructor with a ```const char*``` value of NULL. This is happening SOMEWHERE in your code. Surely, you can find all places where you call the constructor and put some simple debug print statements to see where it may be doing so.

Comment: *With a codebase that's big, it's hard to pinpoint the problem.* -- No it isn't.  It could be a million lines.  That is a very targeted message -- any time a C++ exception is thrown, the location is one of the simplest things to debug and inspect.  A debugger and looking at the call stack will show you exactly what causes that error.